# how can I check if I have sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, google-xml-sitemaps

maybe it's a very stupid question but I'm just getting into wordpress and I installed a plugin `Google XML Sitemaps` and activated it, but I'm not quite sure that it really provides me with sitemap.xml how can I check that?

when I go to mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml

I can see site map information, so I guess it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Then it works. Add a new post and see if it changes.

You can submit your sitemap to search engines but they will eventually pick it up regardless. Just give it time to see results -- it's not instant.

Use Google Console
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list to make sure it's getting picked up.